# Magento Purchase Order Endpoint

Tags: magento2, rest-api, purchase-order

I'm searching for Purchase Order endpoint in Magento 2 rest API here https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.2/. it seems that it's not available.
There's an order endpoint but I believe it's for the sales order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your version of Magento. Your link won't load for me; but if you really do need a purchase order REST API endpoint for 2.2, then you're out of luck. These endpoints weren't introduced until 2.4.x.

For 2.4.x, you'll want to visit [this link](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/), and search for `purchase-order`. That should at least get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I saw some endpoints available for purchase-order but i can't see where i can get the list of all purchase-order.

Comment: From what I can tell, Magento doesn't provide this functionality. If you open vendor/magento/module-purchase-order/etc/webapi.xml and review the endpoints configured here, you'll see that none of them appear to provide a list of all purchase orders. I think you'll need to build a custom endpoint, and the devdocs are not especially clear on how to do this. I would start with this tutorial and search for others to supplement whatever else you need to know: https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/.

Comment: will try this one and keep you posted. Thanks!